# Shell script to get file name based on pattern from a string

Tags: string, shell

We need a pattern to get the filename from the string below:-

```
data="prod2-01_httpd-prod-80_access_referer_log.20181111-060000"
```

The filename which is required is `access_referer_log.20181111-060000`, so basically I need all the values after port number 80.

One more data example:

```
prod1-01_ftpd6-21_xferlog.20181030-100000.
```

In this case `filename` should be `xferlog.20181030-100000`.

Comment: Please always post some of the research which you have done regarding the topic of your question. Refer this section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the port number always preceeded by a "-" character?'  Is the string in a file (IE you have a file of rows of data and you want to extract filenames from data in the file), or a variable in a script?